# How to Let Style Overwrite Other Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="Frame0" TargetType="Shape">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

<Canvas x:Name="canvas" Height="346" Width="643">
    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource Frame0}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Height="77" Canvas.Left="26" Canvas.Top="13" Width="119" />
</Canvas>
```

I want anyone who uses my resource dictionary to always obey my rules. My style should be in the first priority. How to achieve that? Currently, **Stroke="Red"** and **StrokeThickness="2"** overwrite my rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to have the style value override the local value, as far as I know.  Looking at the [order of precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx), you'll see that the local value is 3rd on the list, preceded only by [coerced values, and values from active animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#animations).

If you really need to force the value globally, then you could consider making a derived control that sets [coerced values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.coercevalue.aspx) in the appropriate dependency properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can't stop people overriding your properties when they are used this way.

The only way you *might* be able to do it is to create a user control based on a `Rectangle` (or what ever object you want) and don't expose the relevant properties. However, that doesn't stop people just using the `Rectangle` directly.

Answer (score 1):

The order really matters. **Style** has the lowest priority, which means anyone can overwrite it.